# Vim: space-separated list of numbers

Tags: vim

I want to insert a line that looks like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... 100000
```

`:put =range(1,100000)` gives me those numbers separated by newline, but I want them space-separated. How does one go about doing this?

Comment: Why not just `100000J` after running that command?

Comment: because I had no idea what `J` does lol...

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `100000J` after running that command.

The `J` command joins the current line with the next one (roughly speaking, it replaces the newline ending this line with a space). `100000J` does this 100000 times.

Comment: You should probably explain what this does for future readers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `99999J`, so 1 less than the numbers?

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there; I would use `:put =join(range(1,100000))`. The `join()` function concatenates all items in a list, and separates them with space characters. You could also pass in a different separator character if you wanted something other than spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm sure the generalization of the separator character will come in useful at some point.